# Mmap a writecombine region to userspace documentation

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, driver, mmap

According to the following documentation
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/x86/pat.html,

Drivers wanting to export some pages to userspace do it by using mmap interface and a combination of:

pgprot_noncached()

io_remap_pfn_range() or remap_pfn_range() or vmf_insert_pfn()

Note that this set of APIs only works with IO (non RAM) regions. If driver wants to export a RAM region, it has to do set_memory_uc() or set_memory_wc() as step 0 above and also track the usage of those pages and use set_memory_wb() before the page is freed to free pool.

Why is the extra step set_memory_uc() or set_memory_wc() needed for RAM regions?

Answer (score 0):

This is needed since set_memory_uc() and set_memory_wc() are specifically written to work with memory regions; the other API functions you're being told to use here are for I/O regions.

Since you want to work with page(s) in a RAM region using the API functions listed, your driver needs to mark them as uncached or write-combined first so that they can essentially be treated like I/O pages, use the APIs, and then be sure to follow up with explicit writeback(s) of the memory page(s) in order to sync their contents before your driver considers itself "finished" with them.